# Adding view before RootViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I started my application as a navigation based application, and did the main bulk of the work using the tables etc. Now, I wish to create a start view page, consisting of two buttons, one which links to the RootViewController and the other which links to another view.
Is this possible? If so, how would I go about it?
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Question answered!

Comment: better! I can't answer fully right now, but you should look into your application delegate / root XIB which creates the first view to replace the root VC.

Comment: That was where I was thinking of starting, will see how far i can get with it, thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a new UINavigationController with your startview as the `rootViewController` for the window first.

Then on the click event of the first button, make a delegate call to your appDelegate class and remove the present UINavigationController and add the main UINavigationController (which links to your RootViewController)  as the `rootViewController` for the window.

For the second buttons click event you can simply push the next view to the navigationController.

Comment: HI xcode, I used the following method: I created another navigation controller in my mainwindow.xib, then linked the view controller etc to that. It works, but there is a navigation bar on my first view (that I am linking to my root view). I don't want this navigation bar there, when I try and hide it, the navigation bar disappears from the whole application. Pretty sure theres a problem with the way ive created the navigation controller, not quite sure though, any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: you have to unhide it later. You can do this in the viewWillAppear method of the view controller where you need the navigation bar